# how to use delete inside a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have to use manually the delete operation
`delete from t where=col=1`, because if I insert it inside the trigger does not work. I.e. the delete operation doesn't save into `deleted` table.

```
alter trigger trig1 on t
after insert,delete as
set col = case when col1=1.8 then 2

delete from t where col=1;

insert into history(col,col1)
select *
from deleted
```

The table history don't get the insertion.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. I don't see an update. Why would you need to update the same table you are inserting to??? A clear explanation of what you trigger needs to do would help us, but more importantly it would help as it seems you are not quite sure what it needs to do.

Comment: -1 very poorly asked question. not clear at all what you are after

Comment: @SeanLange because the value I insert changes over time, for this reason I establish the update, this value inserted is not constant. In my original table I have a case that when a row takes a value this row must be deleted. For this reason I want the row under a condition is automatically removed and I don't have to.

Comment: Of course you don't insert a constant value. What would be the point of that? You again mention update...what are you updating? Not sure what kind of bizarre business rule would state that if a row has a certain value it should be updated. Why not just prevent that value from getting in the table? You need to provide a LOT more details before anybody can help you much here.

Comment: @SeanLange My business rule is follows: if in a column is a specific value, trigger have to modify this value by another. If find other specific value, trigger have to deleted the row. Then the deleted rows by the trigger must be inserted into history table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to do this is by dividing the three things you want to do in three parts, two triggers and one stored procedure.

```
create trigger trig1 on t
after insert as
set col = case when col1=1.8 then 2

create procedure p(@t sysname) as
begin
if exists (select * from t where col=1)
delete from t where col=1;
end

create trigger trig2 on t
after delete as
insert into history(col,col1)
select *
from deleted
```

You will have to execute `p` when inserting values.